# How to convert the MongoDB ISO date to Normal date-Mongodb with PHP , and MongoDb driver

Tags: php, mongodb

How to retrive the date which is stored in the below format in mongodb

> "updated_date_time" : ISODate("2015-05-28T05:01:10.966Z")

While I am trying to retrive the ISOdate from mongodb it returns the result like

> "0.03000000 1431921367"

How do we retrive the timestamp and date from mongodb?

Could someone help me to fetch the data..

Comment: Please update your question with which language and driver you are using and how you get the "0.03000000 1431921367" - otherwise we have little chance of helping you

Comment: $cursor=$collection->find(array('first_name'=>$fname1));
 foreach ($cursor as $r) { $v1a= $r['updated_date_time']; }  this is how  am retriving the data  .. while retriving i got the output as  "0.03000000 1431921367"..could you suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depens in what language you're working. In Javascript you should use moment.js to save and retrieve information. It's easy to use.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response. Am trying to retrive the datas using mongodb with PHP

Comment: Just look at this documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php . Hope it helps !